# Add separator to string at every N characters Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to put a colon after 3 characters. So "123:456:789:0" I want to print it. How can I do this. The way it outputs now : "123:4567890"

```
String s = "1234567890";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G.{3})")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try below regular expression,

```
String s = "1234567890";
s = s.replaceAll("(.{3})", "$1:");
System.out.println(s);
```

Update:
Updated the answer, if you don't want to insert ':' at the end,

```
String s = "123456789";
s = s.replaceAll("...(?!$)", "$0:");
System.out.println(s);
```

"..." is the length. Which you can change if you want to. So if you want 84:F3:EB:34:75:6B like this as the output of 84F3EB34756B then use,

```
s = s.replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0:");
```

Comment: s.replaceAll does not replace the characters in the string, since strings are immutable. It does however return the string with replaced characters. You would need to do something like `s=s.replaceAll(...)`. Also, in the case that the string is of length 9, you tack on an extra colon that is not necessary to the end. Fixed code = +1 from me :)

Comment: 84:F3:EB:34:75:6B: In the form of, the end of the last figure ":" should not put the sign. 2-up when I disconnected.

Comment: I think you mean to say that you don't want ":" at the end of String right? If yes then refer my updated answer. If not please explain.

Comment: how we can add the separator from right, something like:    100,000

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bruteforce method of doing things, and is probably highly inefficient. It will work however

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "123456789";
    String result="";
    for(int i=1; i < s.length()+1; i++)
    {
      result += s.charAt(i-1);
      if(i%3 == 0 && i!=s.length())
      {
        result+=":";
      }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without regular expressions.

```
fun String.putDots(step: Int = 3, divider: String = ":"): String {
        if (isEmpty() || length <= step) {
            return this
        }

        val builder = StringBuilder()

        var startIndex = 0

        for (i in step..lastIndex step step) {
            builder.append(substring(startIndex, i))

            builder.append(divider)

            startIndex = i
        }

        builder.append(substring(startIndex, length))

        return builder.toString()
    }
```